# How to make kafka-console-consumer.sh consume all partitions of a given topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 32 partitions for example, and I find that "kafka-console-consumer.sh" only consumes up to 18 partitions out of those 32 when I try to monitor the messages of the topic with "kafka-console-consumer.sh".  How do I make "kafka-console-consumer.sh" consume messages from all partitions of a given topic?

I felt "kafka-console-consumer.sh" consumes only 18 out of 32 partitions by looking at its log as following:
[image]

Comment: It already consumes all partitions... How do you know there's even messages in those partitions?

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited the question with a screenshot, do I interpret the log correctly?

Comment: can you try this command and check consumer position `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group` @JamesYu

Comment: Every time you start a console consumer without a group id, a random one is chosen for you. If you have not waited at least a week (the default retention) for messages to expire on the topic, you'll always see offset zero. There is no code I know of in the consumer that limits how many partitions are consumed at once, and 18 seems like a random number... My point is that you should be using `GetOffsetShell` instead to check the latest offsets of the topic